# Does full motor current pass through 'switches' on children's driving vehicles?

Tags: mobile-robot

I plan to hijack a powerwheels-like toy to control it with the jetson nano.  Here is the toy:

https://www.wayfair.com/outdoor/pdp/konbeca-ride-on-bumper-car-kids-toy-electric-funny-ride-on-car-for-360-spin-powered-knbe1220.html?piid=59995891

I want to keep it ultra simple so my idea is to just take off the 'handles'(levers) and hook the wires to two relays controlled by the Jetson.

What I do not understand is if the full 30amp current goes through these wires, so that I would need heavy duty relays, or if some little relays than just take like up to 10amps are fine since it's just a 'switch'.

Comment: where did you get the 30 A spec?

Comment: @jsotola - there's probably a fuse rated for 30A.

Comment: I believe I heard from discussions about 'motor controller'  that amps could get up to 30.  ie when people add their own motor controllers to powerwheels, it can have that much current.   but I don't understand if that is the same circuit as a switch to go forward/backward.  Ideally I'd like a very small solid state relay, not a big clunky mechanical or big expensive solid state. I don't want to burn up my relays or jetson eg because the vehicle drew 30 amps when stalled up hill.

Comment: You could just measure the current...

Comment: @Ben ...We could all rediscover all knowledge for ourselves, but we prefer to just ask those who know,  while we work on other things which are novel ;)  That said, I have no tool for testing, so that'd just be an extra expense, and also I haven't yet received the toy so I'm trying to get ahead on purchasing relays. I'm certainly not the first to do something like this.  I'm losing faith in this robotics exchange :(.  it's quite hostile.

Comment: @AwokeKnowing you are forgetting that you are talking about a toy, something that is designed to work for a few months ... nobody, except the manufacturer knows for sure what is inside the toy ... a production change could be done at any time without any warning ... you will have to determine how it is wired when you receive it

Comment: @jsotola So I'm perfectly happy with an actual answer of what is likely/unlikely and how to know/test.  If it seems to you that it's perfectly likely that the wires that are pulling the full current to a motor have the switch right there inline, if that 'could be' then fine.  Or if it's like 'no, people don't put the direction switches on the wires that pull the full motor current' then great.    I know perfectly the situation and I've been on stackexchange forever. I know the drill. This shouldn't be a 'elitist tech club' where new people are told to go get an electronics degree.

Comment: @AwokeKnowing I had a closer look at the link that you posted ... it turns out that the toy is made in USA ... so I would expect the quality to be better than average ... that makes me think that the control switches are only low current ... it is also possible that the joysticks are not directly electrical, but mechanically linked to control relays

Comment: @jsotola thanks, well I guess when it comes in a couple days I'll look what the lever switches connect to and see if it looks like they're connected into some 'signal' input on a motor controller.  to me it seems they wouldn't risk putting the full current directly from battery to motor right through where kids might rip off and touch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer is that indeed, the motor current wires are exactly the same wires wired into the switches:

[image]

This is apparently the univerally most common way these things are wired, and it would be good for people on this robotics site to be aware of that.

I hope this future robotics prototypers hooking up computers to these toys.  My 10-amp relays have not burned out yet, though I have no  idea how much current they get when eg the toy is pushing against a wall.